# jQuery touchstart conflict with nicescroll on IE

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, touch

Im use this code for creating a menu on side left but on IE 11 not working, only work on Firefox, Chrome, Edge and all other major browser.

Please can you help me?

When i touch the menu with class `.morph-main-menu-button-wrapper` on IE 11 not showing nothing.

But if i make a double touch on this icon the menu is showing!

After deleting all js code the problem is nicescrool:

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(
function() {
$("html").niceScroll({
cursorcolor:        "#40A9F2",
cursorwidth:        "12px",
cursorborder:       "0px solid #000",
cursorborderradius: "3px",
scrollspeed:        90,
autohidemode:       true,
background:         '#ddd',
hidecursordelay:    400,
cursorfixedheight:  false,
cursorminheight:    20,
enablekeyboard:     true,
horizrailenabled:   false,
bouncescroll:       true,
smoothscroll:       true,
iframeautoresize:   true,
emulatetouch:       false,
hwacceleration: true
});
}
);})(jQuery);
```

How to use nicescroll if make conflict with touch?

```
jQuery('.morph-main-menu-button-wrapper, .morph-main-menu-activator').on('touchstart touches touchend click', function(e) {
'use strict';
    e.preventDefault();
        if(jQuery('.morph-main-wrapper').hasClass('morph-main-wrapper-active'))
        {       
            /* hide morph slide */
            jQuery('.morph-main-wrapper').removeClass('morph-main-wrapper-active');
            /* hide morph background */
            jQuery('.morph-main-background').removeClass('morph-main-background-active');
            /* hide background overlay */
            jQuery('.morph-background-overlay').removeClass('morph-background-overlay-active');
            /* hide expanded menu button */
            jQuery('.morph-main-menu-button-wrapper').removeClass('morph-menu-active');

            /* when menu de-activated, animate main menu items */
            jQuery('.morph-menu-wrapper').removeClass('morph-menu-wrapper-active');

            /* hide search field close button */
            jQuery('.morph-search-close-wrapper').removeClass('morph-search-close-wrapper-active');
            /* hide search field */
            jQuery('.morph-search-wrapper').removeClass('morph-search-wrapper-active');
            jQuery('.morph-search-wrapper #searchform #s').blur();
            /* show search button */
            jQuery('.morph-search-button').removeClass('morph-search-button-hidden');

            /* hide secondary menu */
            jQuery('.morph-secondary-menu-wrapper').removeClass('morph-secondary-menu-wrapper-active');
            /* secondary menu button inactive state */
            jQuery('.morph-secondary-menu-button').removeClass('morph-secondary-menu-button-active');
        } else {        
            /* show morph slide */
            jQuery('.morph-main-wrapper').addClass('morph-main-wrapper-active');
            /* show morph background */
            jQuery('.morph-main-background').addClass('morph-main-background-active');
            /* show background overlay */
            jQuery('.morph-background-overlay').addClass('morph-background-overlay-active');
            /* hide expanded menu button */
            jQuery('.morph-main-menu-button-wrapper').addClass('morph-menu-active');

            /* when menu activated, animate main menu items */
            jQuery('.morph-menu-wrapper').addClass('morph-menu-wrapper-active');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 3.7.3 fixed touch problems!

https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/releases

Answer (score 0):

Since there is an issue with the style not applying this leads me to believe there is something in your CSS that is not rendering in IE. Your javascript itself looks fine and should be triggering on all the events. Try adding on touch to be even more safe.

Also you can use $ to referancce jquery, making

```
            jQuery('.morph-menu-wrapper').removeClass('morph-menu-wrapper-active');
```

become 
`$('.morph-menu-wrapper').removeClass('morph-menu-wrapper-active');`

Comment: Nothing, but if i make a double touch on this icon the menu is showing! Only single touch not working, double touch = right click i think on touch devices

Comment: Ok the problem is nicescrool  
(function($){
$(document).ready(
function() {
$("html").niceScroll({
cursorcolor:  "#40A9F2",
cursorwidth:   "12px",
cursorborder:   "0px solid #000",
cursorborderradius: "3px",
scrollspeed:   90,
autohidemode:   true,
background:   '#ddd',
hidecursordelay:  400,
cursorfixedheight:  false,
cursorminheight:  20,
enablekeyboard:  true,
horizrailenabled:  false,
bouncescroll:   true,
smoothscroll:   true,
iframeautoresize:  true,
emulatetouch:       false,
hwacceleration: true
});
}
);})(jQuery);